# Java awt swing, start/stop button with timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a simple application that changes the color of a label when an action is performed.

When I click the button for my application(the action being performed), the color of the text of the label will continuously change on an interval set by the timer.

Now, what I am trying to accomplish is to have my button have the functionality of starting and stopping the change in color for the text of the label.

I am able to have it start, but I think there is a flaw in my logic when trying to stop execution of the change in color.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   
        Timer timer = new Timer(500, timerListener);
        while(!timer.isRunning())
        {
            if(!timer.isRunning())
            {
                button.setText("Stop");
                timer.start();
            }
            else
            {
                timer.stop();
                button.setText("Start");
            }
}
```

Without the contents following the "else" I am able to start the program, but not stop it.

Please review and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the code above creates a new timer each time the method is invoked. So the reference to the old timer is lost, which is why calling `stop()` has no effect.

(Sorry for also posting this as a comment, but after I typed it all in I realized it might be the entire answer, not just a note about programming style.  So I added it as an answer.)

For comparison, here's some working code of mine that does something similar.  Notice I only create a new timer in the case where I'm going to be starting a new timing event.  The stop case just stops the existing timer, it never creates one.

```
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
  {
     if( timing ) {
        timing = false;
        timer.stop();
        view.setStartButtonText( "start stting" );
        view.setTimerLabel( "stopped" );
        view.setBackground( Color.CYAN.darker() );
     } else {
        nanoTime = System.nanoTime();
        view.setStartButtonText( "stop stting" );
        timing = true;
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer( 1000,
                new ActionListener()
                {
                   @Override
                   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
                   {
                      long minuteTime = ( System.nanoTime() -
                      nanoTime ) /
                      ( 60_000_000_000L );
                      view.setTimerLabel( minuteTime + " minutes" );
                      if( minuteTime > 50 )
                         if( darkBg ) {
                            view.setBackground( Color.PINK );
                            darkBg = false;
                         } else {
                            view.setBackground( Color.PINK.
                                    darker() );
                            darkBg = true;
                         }
                   }
                } );
        timer.setRepeats( true );
        timer.start();
     }
  }
```